# Silex v1.3 to Silex v2: Twig_Error_Runtime

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig, silex

I recently migrated my Silex v1.3 project where everything is worked fine, to the Silex v2. I get a twig error where I don't understand the cause

```
Twig_Error_Runtime in Template.php line 590:

Neither the property "request" nor one of the methods "request()", "getrequest()"/"isrequest()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Silex\Application" in "index.twig" at line 5
```

Here is the 5 first lines of my index.twig file

```
{% extends "layout.twig" %}


{% block stylsheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/public/libs/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-minimal.css" />
```

And of course in the layout, I call the

```
{% block stylsheets %}{% endblock %}
```

But I'm not sure at all, the problem is on the twig file...
Is something has to be change ?

Here is an extract of the controller:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {

    return $app['twig']->render('index.twig', [
        ...
    ]);
})->bind('homepage');
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that `app.request.uri` wasn't working anymore with recent Twig.

But if you use `global.request.uri` it works fine.

I did not find any information in Twig's documentation about that.

Comment: Just upvoted this as it did the trick for me - bit perplexed as to why the chosen answer didn't work for me. How did you find this out out of curiosity?

Comment: Both answers works for me, but I agree it is easier to change app.request into global.request

Comment: @mikelovelyuk I found out by reading the code :( and a month ago I found this : http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html#global-variable

Answer (score 5):

As seblucas said, `global.request.uri` works fine. But I found another solution to resolve this issue. You can replace `app.request.uri` by `app.request_stack.currentrequest.basepath`. I don't know what is the best solution...

Comment: global variable doesn't exist in my case, but app.request_stack.currentrequest.basepath's done a job.